Minha API está retornando os dados como Null
Minha Api está retornando os dados como Null toda vez que mando uma imagem.
 <?php 
    
    function api_photo_post($request) {
      $user = wp_get_current_user();
      $user_id = $user->ID;
    
      if($user_id === 0) {
        $response = new WP_Error('error', 'Usuário não possui permissão.', ['status' => 401]);
        return rest_ensure_response($response);
      }
    
      $nome = sanitize_text_field($request['nome']);
      $idade = sanitize_text_field($request['idade']);
      $files = $request->get_file_params();
    
      if(empty($nome) || empty($idade) || empty($files)) {
        $response = new WP_Error('error', 'Dados incompletos.', ['status' => 422]);
        return rest_ensure_response($response);
      }
    
      $response = [
        'post_author' => $user_id,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_title' => $nome,
        'post_content' => $nome,
        'files' => $files,
        'meta_input' => [
          'idade' => $idade,
          'acessos' => 0,
        ],
      ];
    
      $post_id = wp_insert_post($response);
    
      require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php';
      require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php';
      require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php';
    
      $photo_id = media_handle_upload('img', $post_id);
      update_post_meta($post_id, 'img', $photo_id);
      
     
    
      return rest_ensure_response($response);
    }
    
    function register_api_photo_post() {
      register_rest_route('api', '/photo',[
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'api_photo_post',
      ]);
    }
    
    add_action('rest_api_init', 'register_api_photo_post');
?>

Erro
Como posso resolver?

Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada).
